# Brothers Divided

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

*Weird given they're both united...*

Police! This man stole my _____! (5) [4]
1989 Metal album by Alice Cooper (5) [5]
Something Rome did in 476 (4) [1]
Gnarly, rad, tubular even (4) [3]
Unit of length equal to about 0.914 m (4) [5]
Potato-based "French" side dish (5) [1]
Can be cotton, rock or eye (5) [5]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The divided brothers are ...

> ... the **United Kingdom** and the **United States of America**. They are both "united", but not with each other.

First, ...

> ... solve the clues. The number in round brackets is the number of letters in each answer.
>
>  Police! This man stole my _____!        **PURSE**
>  1989 Metal album by Alice Cooper        **TRASH**
>  Something Rome did in 476               **FALL**
>  Gnarly, rad, tubular even               **COOL**
>  Unit of length equal to about 0.914 m   **YARD**
>  Potato-based "French" side dish         **FRIES**
>  Can be cotton, rock or eye              **CANDY**

Next, ...

> ... we want to extract a single word from these answers. The [word](/questions/tagged/word) tag tells us so. We could use the number in square brackets as poition of a letter, but unfortunately, the fifth clue's position exceeds its length.
>
>  Note how each of the words is American, where another word would be used in Britain. (That doesn't necessarily apply to all meanings of a word and not always to the exact meaning used in the clue, as in fall and yard.)
>
>  We must find the British equivalent for each of the answers and then extract the letter at the position given in square brackets:
>
>  purse – HAN[**D**]BAG
>  trash – RUBB[**I**]SH
>  fall – [**A**]UTUMN
>  cool – SP[**L**]ENDID
>  yard – GARD[**E**]N
>  fries – [**C**]HIPS
>  candy – SWEE[**T**]S
>
>  So the final answer is, appropriately, **DIALECT**.

Comment: Nice work +1, but *cough* as a Brit, I think your fifth one should be rot13(tneqra)...

Comment: Well, you are obviously the authority here, @Stiv. (I often don't know the exact meaning of words, especially for everyday things, and I found that one with the help of a decitionary.)

Comment: Good job! Also despite finding the "wrong" word for the 4th one, you still managed. My original idea used fvpx (although yours works quite well too)